# Im having an issue with displaying javascript output without any user action

Tags: javascript, html

this is the Question: An integer is said to be prime if it is greater than 1 and divisible only by 1 and itself. For example, 2, 3, 5 and 7 are prime, but 4, 6, 8 and 9 are not.

a) Write a function that determines whether a number is prime. 
b) Use this function in a script that determines and prints all the prime numbers between 1 and 10000.

How many of these 10000 numbers do you really have to test before being sure that you have found all the primes? Display the results in a `<textrarea>`.

This is my code:

```
    function isPrime(n)
    {
        boolean prime=true;
            if(n==1 || n==0)
            {

                prime= false;
            }

            if(n==2)
            {
                prime= true;
            }
            else
            {
                for(int i=2;i<n;i++)
                {
                    if(n%i==0)
                    {
                        prime= false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return prime;
    }
    function printPrimes()
    {
        document.writeln("<textarea rows="10" cols="15">");
        for(var i=0; i<=1000; i++)
        {
            if(isPrime(i)==true)
            {
                document.writeln("<p>" + i + "</p>");
            }
        }
        document.writeln("</textarea>");
    }
    printPrimes();
```

This is My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="prime.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Prime numbers between 1 and 1000 are: </h1>
    </body>
```

When i open the html file on chrome only the header shows up the script doesnt seem to run!

Comment: display the results in a <textarea> tag. ** sorry ddnt post properly for some reason

Comment: This sounds like a project-euler question.

Comment: The script is in the head and run immediately, so your `document.writeln`'s are being written to the `<head>`, which is not visible in the document (by default). Also, You haven't closed your `<html>` tag

Comment: `for(int i=2;i<n;i++)` Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're importing the script in the `<head>`, so that's where it's output will go. Try moving it to the `<body>`.

That's possibly the slowest way to find primes.

*edit* — another problem is this:

```
            for(int i=2;i<n;i++)
```

There is no `int` keyword in JavaScript - it's `var`. That would cause a syntax error, which would show up in the error console.  Neither is there a `boolean` keyword (declaration of "prime"). It's important to keep the error console open while doing any HTML/JavaScript development.

Comment: javascript automatically injects the script into the body, ive been writing many similar primitive programs, this isnt the issue, but for the record i did try to move it to the body and the same thing happened. the issue is the script code itself. first of all, sorry for the missing html closing tag and the for(int i) instead of var i, i fixed those, and still no go, there is something wrong with the script itself, if anyone could show me the right way to write the code for this script and html t would be a great help, still a javascript beginner.

Comment: Updating answer - you really need to look in the JavaScript error console as step 1 when you're having problems.

Comment: Also, JavaScript does not automatically inject the script into the body. It may be that the browser (sometimes) shows you content in the `<head>`, but that's a bad practice one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are attempting to write the `<textarea>` to the `<head>` element. Try loading/executing your script within the `<body>`.